# MySQL : How to get query from joined 2 tables with records occured twice

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables (`tbseabuy and tbseasell`), `tbseabuy` is table for holding records for buying charges from vendor, while `tbseasell` holds record for selling charges to customer.
Let's say **`tbseabuy`** have columns as follows :

| fjobkey | fseq | idcharges | fhargabeli | fdescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 463 | 0 | 54 | 15000 | AIR FREIGHT CHARGES |
| 463 | 1 | 379 | 40000 | JASA HANDLING |
| 463 | 2 | 379 | 40000 | JASA HANDLING |

Now with **`tbseasell`**, the columns as follows :

| fjobkey | fseq | idcharges | fhargajual | fdescription |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 463 | 0 | 379 | 100000 | JASA HANDLING |

Now, I need mysql query which will result as follows :

| fjobkey | idcharges | fdescription | fhargajual | fhargabeli | fprofit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 463 | 54 | AIR FREIGHT CHARGES | 15000 | 0 | 0 |
| 463 | 379 | JASA HANDLING | 100000 | 40000 | 60000 |
| 463 | 379 | JASA HANDLING | 100000 | 40000 | 60000 |

so, the query result will look for all charges, if no connection between `idcharges`, then only show which field come first, whether `fhargajual` or `fhargabeli`, but if there is connection, then will take which row count is the largest and combine it.

Anyone can help, thanks

Comment: i'm stumped reading the question, *"if no connection between `idcharges`, then only show which field come first."* i'm not sure what does *"which field come first,"* is the order decided by `fseq`? also you said that *"but if there is connection, then will take which row count is the largest and combine it"* however i cant find out what are getting "combined."

Comment: @BagusTesa, let's say this, if tbseabuy have a row while tbseasell not existed, then the row still show nevertheless, but if tbseabuy have one row while tbseasell existed but more than one row, then it will show the maximum rows either tbseabuy or tbseasell

Comment: *"it will show the maximum rows either tbseabuy or tbseasell"* - so actually whichever value is the largest between `fhargajual` and `fhargabeli` for the corresponding row will be the `fhargajual` and the smaller one become `fhargabeli`? perhaps a sample data to show all possible cases would be helpful to avoid misinterpretation.

Answer (score 3):

To determine which records are connected by *idcharges* and which are not, we can use the `LEFT JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT b.fjobkey,
       b.idcharges,
       b.fdescription,
       CASE
         WHEN s.fjobkey IS NULL THEN b.fhargabeli
         ELSE s.fhargajual
       END AS fhargajual,
       CASE
         WHEN s.fjobkey IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE b.fhargabeli
       END AS fhargabeli,
       CASE
         WHEN s.fjobkey IS NULL THEN 0
         ELSE s.fhargajual - b.fhargabeli
       END AS fprofit
FROM   tbseabuy b
       LEFT JOIN tbseasell s
              ON s.fjobkey = b.fjobkey
                 AND s.idcharges = b.idcharges;
```

Results :

```
fjobkey idcharges fdescription        fhargajual    fhargabeli  fprofit
463     54        AIR FREIGHT CHARGES 15000         0           0
463     379       JASA HANDLING       100000        40000    60000
463     379       JASA HANDLING       100000        40000    60000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7cQPZ0XD)

Comment: i just realized the result order would different between mysql version 5.7 and 8. this does query work, but i do wonder if op still have something we dont know, especially that order and combine.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the sequence of data existence, where "first" denotes data from the table `tbseabuy`, Let's wait their explanations in case I've made a mistake.

Comment: agreed, i'm about to post an answer similar to yours - bar the order by - but the last paragraph made me confused and then stop.

Comment: i don't know what to say, it WORKS, amazing.. no wonder this stackoverflow become place for master and newbie sharing. kudos